# Java EE / EJB vs Spring for Distributed Transaction management with multiple DB Clusters

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jakarta-ee, ejb

I have a requirement to produce a prototype (running in a J2EE compatible application server with MySQL) demonstrating the following

- Demonstrate ability to distribute a transaction over multiple database located at different sites globally (Application managed data replication)
- Demonstrate ability to write a transaction to a database from a choice of a number of database clusters located at multiple locations. The selection of which database to write to is based on user location. (Database managed data replication)

I have the option to choose either a Spring stack or a Java EE stack (EJB etc). It would be useful to know of your opinions as to which stack is better at supporting distributed transactions on multiple database clusters.

If possible, could you also please point me to any resources you think would be useful to learn of how to implement the above using either of the two stacks. I think seeing examples of both would help in understanding how they work and probably be in a better position to decide which stack to use.

I have seen a lot of sites by searching on Google but most seem to be outdated (i.e. pre EJB 3 and pre Spring 3)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the JavaEE stack the following way:

- configure a XA `DataSource` for each database server
- according to user's location, a Stateless EJB looks up the corresponding DataSource and get the connection from it
- when broadcasting a transaction into all servers, a `Stateless` EJB has to iterate on all configured DataSources to execute one or more queries on them, but in a single transaction

In case of a technical failure, the transaction is rolled back on all concerned servers. In case of a business failure, the code can trigger a rollback thanks to `context.setRollbackOnly()`.

That way, you benefit from JavaEE automatic distributed transaction demarcation first, and then you can use more complex patterns if you need to manage transaction manually.

BUT the more servers you have enlisted in your transaction, the longest the two-phase commit operation will last, moreover if you have high latency between systems. And I doubt MySQL is the best relational database implementation to do such complex distributed transactions.

Comment: Thanks Yves. That is interesting. How would the same be impmlemented in Spring. I am trying to get an idea as to how different the implementation is between the Spring Stack and the Java EE stack.

Comment: It would be really similar with Spring but you have to setup a distributed transaction manager implementation (if deploying in Tomcat for instance), configure transaction demarcation and isolation level, I consider an overhead when JavaEE defaults suit your needs. Depending on your persistence layer, you will have to do DataSource routing with Spring

Comment: Is it possible to use Spring but use JavaEE for the transaction manager? I am using Jboss 7 AS

Comment: Of course yes. But I find it more risky to build a "sounds-complex" application with a mixed of technology when only one may be enough. In case of troubles, diagnosing the involved parts will more difficult.